# MS ACCESS - Query

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that lists invoices and applications. I want the query to bring back the list of invoices but only bring any applications that have had a tick box pressed.

the two fields are as follows:

"Document_type" - "Invoice" or "Application" 
"Add_APP_WIP" - if application is classed as an invoice this tick box is pressed.

would this be done the query criteria? so list all invoices and all applications but only if application has "Add_APP_WIP" ticked.

[image]

For instance in the image above only the one application should show in the list and all the invoices. but application without the tick should not appear in the query.

[image]

Comment: We can't answer this. [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). 
Please [provide](http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) sample data and expected result.

Comment: I have added a picture to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done using a query. Please update the table name as per your db.

```
Select Document_type from Invoice where Document_type='Invoice'
Union all
Select Document_type from Invoice where Document_type='Application' And Add_APP_WIP = true
```

Comment: is it possible to do this within an existing query rather than from record sets, perhaps in the criteria? as the query list more controls than just those two. see edit with image showing.

Comment: Add this filter `where Add_APP_WIP= true OR Document_Type='Invoice'`

Comment: I have added this to the filter but it still seems to show all the records.